# Where can i save my block in cakephp directory structure that will contain all my menu links?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create my custom theme in CakePHP. Where can I save my block in CakePHP directory structure that will contain all my menu links? And how can I fetch the file from `View\Themed\MyTheme\Layouts\default.ctp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access: `View\Themed\MyTheme\Layouts\default.ctp`, in (Cake 2.1+), you must tell cake which theme you want to use like so:

```
public $theme = 'MyTheme';
// or override in an action:
$this->theme = 'MyTheme';
```

Then:

```
$this->layout = 'default';
```

will refer to your `View\Themed\MyTheme\Layouts\default.ctp`.

If cake can't find the requested view file in `MyTheme`, it will fallback to `app/View` to find it.

In this way you can override views in your theme as needed.

So if you place your menu in `View/Elements/menu.ctp`, all of your themes will be able to access it. if you want to overwrite it for `MyTheme`, simply create an `Elements/menu.ctp` within `MyTheme`.

The process is slightly different with previous versions of cake if I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Either use [Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) (if your navbar shows on every single view) or use [View Blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks) (if navbar only shows on some views).

In your default.ctp file you would just do..

```
echo $this->element('navbar');
```

Which would render Views/Elements/navbar.ctp onto Views/Layouts/default.ctp (if you are using the default layout).

Answer (score 0):

Just place it under `/App/Views/Layouts`. If you want to use it everywhere, call it `default.ctp`, it will automatically be used. Otherwise, give it a different name, and then in the controller do:

```
public function some_action() {
    $this->layout = 'mylayout';
}
```

This will display `some_action` using your layout instead of the default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But actually i want to know, that i have a navigation div and i wan to make it dynamic and want to fetch using $this->fetch() like <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>. if it is possible then how to separate the navigation div from the default.ctp file and if it is not possible then please give me a solution to do it.